# VBA date formatting won't work

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'll get right to it, I can't seem to get the date in my macros to print in the format I'd like ("30 June 2017" for example)

Here's how I have gotten on so far:

```
Sub TopDate()

  Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Dim mBefore As Date
  mBefore = Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Date - 1), "mmmm d yyyy")
  Selection.InsertBefore mBefore
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

End Sub
```

I reuse old documents as templates, ideally I'd just highlight the old date, hit a shortcut and be done with it.

I've been stuck on this for about half an hour now embarrassingly, would really appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Comment: If you like the format as in the example you gave ("30 June 2017") then change the following line:
mBefore = Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Date - 1), "mmmm d yyyy")
to:
mBefore = Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Date - 1), "dd mmmm yyyy")

Comment: didn't work. :(

Comment: What did you get? What is the error?

Comment: It just prints 30/06/2017 instead of 30 June 2017.
Restarting didn't help, a different machine didn't help. Feel like I've lost my mind haha

Comment: If you want to format the output on the excel sheet then you should use the following: Selection.NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, where should I insert this? I'm using word btw

Comment: Try it right after Selection.InsertBefore mBefore

Comment: Just get hit with a compile error: Method or data member not found

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
mBefore = Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Date - 1), "mmmm d yyyy")
```

to

```
mBefore = Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Date - 1), "d mmmm yyyy")
```

to get format such as `30 June 2017`. But I wonder something as simple as this will give you issues so must be you are not asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using Word VBA (that should have been part of the question).
So the code to insert formatted date should be the following:

```
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd MMMM yyyy"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```